# Is there a limit to the size of database I can use in an Android OS app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, size, restrictions

I have wanted to build an Android app for a long time now, and I just haven't had time to try to learn how to make it so I have outsourced it to a reputable company in India. My app is a really simple db driven reader app. Initially, the development company said there was no problem with my app idea, they'd have it done in 2 weeks.

But then, they got back to me and said that my content is too large for the Android OS, and that it wasn't possible to make. For content, I have the text of a book in different languages that is simply displayed. Each sqlite db is about 12-15 mb.

Is it true that the OS can't handle db's of that size? THat doesn't seem right. If that is true, what can I do to get around the issue? Do any of you have experience with this issue?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no limit of the database size, instead you can limit you database size programmitically using `setMaximumSize(DB_SIZE)`. As long as your device has sufficient storage your database will grow according the size of data.

Refer this thread : http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a743a3a5a6f5f353?pli=1